# Signing Big PDF files using PDBOX

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox

I'm working on a project used for signing PDF files via Adobe AATL certificates and I'm using the PDFBOX library. My code below is working for files that are smaller than 4MB and breaks for files that are bigger.

**NOTE:** the code below does not throw an exception. However, the file that it signed is not opening due to integrity issue.

[image]

```
public void signDetached(PDDocument document, File inFile, SignProperties sigProps)
        throws IOException {
    int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(document);
    if (accessPermissions == 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No changes to the document are permitted due to DocMDP transform parameters dictionary");
    }

    // create signature dictionary
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    signature.setName(sigProps.getName());
    signature.setLocation(sigProps.getLocation());
    signature.setReason(sigProps.getReason());

    // the signing date, needed for valid signature
    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    // Optional: certify 
    if (accessPermissions == 0)
        SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 2);

    SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
    // Size can vary, but should be enough for purpose.
    signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(SignatureOptions.DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_SIZE * 3);
    // register signature dictionary and sign interface
    document.addSignature(signature, this, signatureOptions);

    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(inFile);

    // write incremental (only for signing purpose)
    document.saveIncremental(stream);
    document.close();
    stream.close();
}
```

**UPDATE:** PDFBOX version is 2.0.8
**Input File** anything bigger than 4 MB

Comment: Please tell what PDFBox version you are using. Please share a signed PDF file. Please include the signing code. Please tell whether the effect also happens when using the unchanged example (CreateSignature.java / CreateVisibleSignature.java from the source code download).

Comment: Please share a file for which your code fails, input and output document. While there indeed might be document size related issues, they should not occur for meager 4 MB.

Comment: Is `inFile` identical to to the input file? That is not good. It should be different.

Comment: The javadoc of saveIncrmental() mentions this: _output - stream to write to. It will be closed when done. It should not point to the source file_.

Comment: The current PDFBox version is 2.0.12. Always use the latest version.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hey man, I updated the question the version of PDFBOX I'm using is 2.0.8 and any file that is bigger than 4MB breaks.

Comment: 2.0.8 is from February 2017 and has unrelated security issues (which should be detected if your maven build uses a plugin to detect risky dependencies). Anyway, my bet is on the saveIncremental parameter overwriting your input file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, hey man you were right about saveIncremental fix. Would you mind placing an answer so I can mark it as an answer and give you an upvote? Thanks for helping me out, I really appreciate it ^_^

Comment: @Tilman *"The javadoc of saveIncrmental() mentions this: [...] It should not point to the source file."* - You might want to make that a bit harsher. Anyone coming from specification reading understands this as "not recommended" but not as "forbidden", i.e. doing this is supported by the library but might cause other issues elsewhere. Please use "must not" if something is not supported by the library. (This admittedly will only help people who actually read the comments...)

Comment: @mkl Yeah I'll do it tonight, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code of yours

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(inFile);
// write incremental (only for signing purpose)
document.saveIncremental(stream);
```

writes into the input file. Don't do that (the javadoc warns about this) because PDFBox also reads from that file when calculating the signature while also writing into it... this results in a really nasty mess. So always save into a different file when signing. And update to the current version.